# Check for the class in an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

If there is an element with the class `myclass` in the `#main` element, I want to alert `ok` but in my example it always shows `no`, how can fix this?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mF2K6/1/

```
<form>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="myclass"></div>
    </div>
    <button>Click Me</button>
</form>


$('button').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //var copy_html = $('#main').clone();
    //if ($('#main').hasClass('myclass')) {
    if ($('#main').is('.myclass')) {
        alert('ok');
    } else {
        alert('no');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check sub-elements for `myclass`, use this:

```
if ($('#main').find('.myclass').length != 0)
```

or this:

```
if ($('#main .myclass').length != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<div id="main">` does not have `myclass` class, only one of its children has it.

You can check the latter with the following code:

```
if ($("#main .myclass").length > 0) {
  alert('ok');
} else {
  alert('no');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    window.alert(isClassPresent() ? "Yes" : "No");
});

function isClassPresent() {
    return $("#main .myclass").length > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work fine：[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mF2K6/4/)

```
var main=$("#main");
$("button").click(function(){
    if(!!main.find(".myclass").length){
        alert("ok");
    }else{
        alert("no");
    };
});
```

[0]`is` method can't to compare different doms!

[1]why must use `live`?

[2]cache `main`(jQuery Object) is more efficient.select only ones.